# How can I set up my site so it works like a post-box?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-on-prem, security

Hard to explain in one line, so full analogy:

You go to the post box to send a paper letter. 30 other people do the same. I can put my letter in, but I can't get other people's letters out. Moreover, you can't see your *own* letter after you have made the decision to post it. Only the recipient of these letters (me) can see them and read them.

I have users from 30-odd organisations who need to submit data in the form of an Excel file. This data is confidential; that is 1) someone from one organisation mustn't be able to see data from another organisation
2) they shouldn't be able to see data from their *own* organisation if they leave their organisation or change their job role.

Obviously as they work for a different organisation to me I can't automate 2) with AD or any other way; the only safe way is for them to be able to upload something, but not read or download something they have uploaded (unfortunately it's unrealistic to expect these organisations to inform me every time someone leaves their role, so I can't even do it manually).

My current way of doing this is with one site that has a separate library for each organisation. This is a lot of work, because every library has to have unique permissions. It fulfills 1), but doesn't fulfill 2) because they need the edit permission in order to be able to upload something to the library.

I'm told I might be able to manage something like the above by using lists, but I don't know how to do that. So if you can shed any light, that would be great.

I am using Sharepoint prem 2013, but my workplace is intending to move to Sharepoint 365 at some point (no-one knows when). So an answer that works for both or has a separate solution for both would be ideal. But if you only know the answer for one or the other, please don't be shy as it will still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I will assume Survey in SharePoint 2013 will be good options for you.

Quote from your requirements:

> 1. someone from one organisation mustn't be able to see data from
>    another organisation 2) they shouldn't be able to see data from their
>    own organisation if they leave their organisation or change their job
>    role.

It is a problem more related to your account managements. In surveys, you can set the users only be able to see/edit the response created by himself, which fits you quite well.

And you do not want to enable users to edit his response once submitted, I will suggest you to use a workflow to remove the users permission to access the survey once he created a new item(Which means he submit the response) in the survey list. As long as you do not grant the user permission again, he will not be able to view the survey list anymore.

For your refereces:

[Create a survey](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)

[Remove permission](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/53ab7928-04a4-45dc-a30e-57f567fab58e/removing-permission-once-submitted-on-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

For SharePoint Online, MS is retiring workflow, so you may need to turn to Power Automate for removing permissions:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Power-Automate-and-SharePoint-Permissions/ba-p/656216

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'll check this out and report back when I have had time to implement it (could be a while)